# How to Integrate GitLab-Ci w/ Azure Kubernetes + Kubectl + ACR for Deployments?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, continuous-integration, gitlab, azure-aks

> Our previous GitLab based CI/CD utilized an Authenticated curl request to a specific REST API endpoint to trigger the redeployment of an updated container to our service, if you use something similar for your Kubernetes based deployment this Question is for you.

### More Background

We run a production site / app (Ghost blog based) on an Azure AKS Cluster.  Right now we manually push our updated containers to a private ACR (Azure Container Registry) and then update from the command line with Kubectl.

That being said we previously used Docker Cloud for our orchestration and fully integrated re-deploying our production / staging services using GitLab-Ci.

That GitLab-Ci integration is the goal, and the 'Why' behind this question.

## My Question

Since we previously used Docker Cloud (doh, should have gone K8s from the start) how should we handle the fact that GitLab-Ci was able to make use of Secrets created the Docker Cloud CLI and then authenticate with the Docker Cloud API to trigger actions on our Nodes (ie. re-deploy with new containers etc).

While I believe we can build a container (to be used by our GitLab-Ci runner) that contains Kubectl, and the Azure CLI, I know that Kubernetes also has a similar (to docker cloud) Rest API that can be found here (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster) — specifically the section that talks about connecting WITHOUT Kubectl appears to be relevant (as does the piece about the HTTP REST API).

My Question to anyone who is connecting to an Azure (or potentially other managed Kubernetes service):

> How does your Ci/CD server authenticate with your Kubernetes service provider's Management Server, and then how do you currently trigger an update / redeployment of an updated container / service?

If you have used the Kubernetes HTTP Rest API to re-deploy a service your thoughts are particularly value-able!

## Kubernetes Resources I am Reviewing

1. [How should I manage deployments with kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37426096/how-should-i-manage-deployments-with-kubernetes?rq=1)
2. [Kubernetes Deployments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34773609/kubernetes-deployments)

Will update as I work through the process.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

### Creating the integration

I had the same problem of how to integrate the GitLab CI/CD with my Azure AKS Kubernetes cluster. I created this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50775758/how-to-add-an-azure-aks-kubernetes-cluster-self-signed-ca-to-gitlab-ci-cd-kubern/50778120) because I was having some error when I tried to add my Kubernetes cluester info into GitLab.

How to integrate them:

1. Inside GitLab, go to "Operations" > "Kubernetes" menu.
2. Click on the "Add Kubernetes cluster" button on the top of the page
3. You will have to fill some form fields, to get the content that you have to put into these fields, connect to your Azure account from the CLI (you need Azure CLI installed on your PC) using `az login` command, and then execute this other command to get the Kubernetes cluster credentials: `az aks get-credentials --resource-group <resource-group-name> --name <kubernetes-cluster-name>`
4. The previous command will create a `~/.kube/config` file, open this file, the content of the fields that you have to fill in the GitLab "Add Kubernetes cluster" form are all inside this `.kube/config` file

These are the fields:

1. **Kubernetes cluster name:** It's the name of your cluster on Azure, it's in the `.kube/config` file too.
2. **API URL:** It's the URL in the field `server` of the `.kube/config` file.
3. **CA Certificate:** It's the field `certificate-authority-data` of the `.kube/config` file, but you will have to base64 decode it.

After you decode it, it must be something like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
some base64 strings here
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

4. **Token:** It's the string of hexadecimal chars in the field `token` of the `.kube/config` file (it might also need to be base 64 decoded?). You need to use a token belonging to an account with **cluster-admin** privileges, so GitLab can use it for authenticating and installing stuff on the cluster. The easiest way to achieve this is by creating a new account for GitLab: create a YAML file with the service account definition (an example can be seen [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/#adding-an-existing-kubernetes-cluster) under *Create a gitlab service account in the default namespace*) and apply it to your cluster by means of `kubectl apply -f serviceaccount.yml`.
5. **Project namespace (optional, unique):** I leave it empty, don't know yet for what or where this namespace can be used.

Click in "Save" and it's done. Your GitLab project must be connected to your Kubernetes cluster now.

### Deploy

In your deploy job (in the pipeline), you'll need some environment variables to access your cluster using the `kubectl` command, here is a list of all the variables available:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/index.html#deployment-variables

To have these variables injected in your deploy job, there are some conditions:

- You must have added correctly the Kubernetes cluster into your GitLab project, menu "Operations" > "Kubernetes" and these steps that I described above
- Your job must be a "deployment job", in GitLab CI, to be considered a deployment job, your job definition (in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`) must have an `environment` key (take a look at the line 31 in this [example](https://gist.github.com/lmcarreiro/75186bd1d4e387c13c63d0a7087e9999#file-gitlab-ci-yml-L31)), and the environment name must match the name you used in menu "Operations" > "Environments".

Here are an example of a [.gitlab-ci.yml](https://gist.github.com/lmcarreiro/75186bd1d4e387c13c63d0a7087e9999) with three stages:

- **Build:** it builds a docker image and push it to gitlab private registry
- **Test:** it doesn't do anything yet, just put an `exit 0` to change it later
- **Deploy:** download a stable version of `kubectl`, copy the `.kube/config` file to be able to run `kubectl` commands in the cluster and executes a `kubectl cluster-info` to make sure it is working. In my project I didn't finish to write my deploy script to really execute a deploy. But this `kubectl cluster-info` command is executing fine.

**Tip:** to take a look at all the environment variables and their values (Jenkins has a page with this view, GitLab CI doesn't) you can execute the command `env` in the script of your deploy stage. It helps a lot to debug a job.

Comment: Great answer! Accepting this one and will add any thoughts on my experience implementing it as I work through the process!  Thanks for putting the time into posting!

Comment: I updated this answer to add some info about the deploy step of this integration process.

Comment: @imcarreiro seriously great work man! Really stoked on this as this was my last question.  I actually got the same general concept working by re-building my build container with Kubectl inside of it and then running commands that way but the native GitLab setup that you have here is really very cool.  I will try this out as soon as I get the chance, I am certainly interested in the accessibility for feature branch testing that this should enable!

Comment: I really tried to do all these things, but still when I push the button "Install Helm" on the gitlab site I get the error "Something went wrong while installing Helm Tiller Kubernetes error." . How should I check that the configuration is right ?

Comment: @igor, take a look at my deploy job in the .gitlab-ci.yml: https://gist.github.com/lmcarreiro/202c61170504239933fe831d382601dd you can try to run the kubectl from the CI job to see if it works...

Comment: should be one of the best answer on all stack overflow jajajaja thanks

Comment: This info is generally correct, and helped me get on the right track for connecting GL and k8s. However, now with RBAC being the default, one more step is needed: creating a service account and giving it the right perms to deploy on k8s (to avoid 403 errors). This step is outlined in the official docs from GL: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/#adding-an-existing-kubernetes-cluster


@lmcarreiro should you maybe add that to your answer since it is the top result (at least for me) when searching for this on Google?

Comment: @EugeneRomero I didn't understand well this additional step, but feel free to edit the answer and add this step by yourself.

Comment: Came here for the third time! That means, this should better be in the gitlab docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Gitlab now does not support certificate based authentication anymore. Instead you need to install agent on you kubernetes cluster. Here is the complete gitlab official documentation for that. Doc mentions GKE and EKS, but solution is cloud agnostic and works for AKS seamlessly.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/install/index.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRR3WuwnxXE

my config.yaml

```
gitops:
  manifest_projects:
  - id: k8s-agent
    default_namespace: default
    paths:
    - glob: 'manifests/*.{yaml,yml,json}'
ci_access:
  groups:
  - id: {your project id}
```

my working .gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

variables:
  K8S_STABLE_VERSION_URL: https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.24.3/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl



build:
  stage: build
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - export DOCKER_VERSION=$(echo "$CI_BUILD_REF" | cut -c 1-6)
    - docker build -t myapp.azurecr.io/myapp/myapp-app:$DOCKER_VERSION .
    - cd ../../ && docker login -u myapp -p $ACR_TOKEN myapp.azurecr.io
    - docker push myapp.azurecr.io/myapp/myapp-app:$DOCKER_VERSION

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - exit 0
  dependencies:
    - build

deploy_dev:
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: Dev
  image: alpine
  script:
    - export DOCKER_VERSION=$(echo "$CI_BUILD_REF" | cut -c 1-6)
    - apk add --no-cache curl
    - curl -LO $K8S_STABLE_VERSION_URL
    - chmod +x ./kubectl
    - mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
    - kubectl config get-contexts
    - kubectl config use-context myapp/g4ak:k8-agent
    - kubectl cluster-info
    - sed -i "s/latest/$DOCKER_VERSION/g" manifests/deployment.yml
    - kubectl apply -f manifests/
  dependencies:
    - build
  only:
    - dev
```

Answer (score -2):

I logged into our GitLab-Ci backend today and saw a 'Kubernetes' button — along with an offer to save $500 at GCP.

[image: $500 at GCP with GitLab-Ci Kubernetes]

### GitLab Kubernetes

URL to hit your repo's Kubernetes GitLab page is:
`https://gitlab.com/^your-repo^/clusters`

As I work through the integration process I will update this answer (but also welcome!).

### Official GitLab Kubernetes Integration Docs

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/index.html

Comment: Of interest: https://about.gitlab.com/2018/08/22/gitlab-11-2-released/#cloud-native-gitlab-helm-chart-generally-available