# How to add an Azure AKS Kubernetes Cluster self-signed CA to GitLab CI/CD Kubernetes integration?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I'm trying to add my Azure AKS Kubernetes cluster to my GitLab CI/CD Kubernetes integration.

I can execute `kubectl` commands on the cluster from my pc, after I ran this command:

`az aks get-credentials --resource-group <resource-group-name> --name <kubernetes-cluster-name>`

It created a `.kube/config` file with a content like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: <some long base64 string here>
    server: https://<resource-group-name+some-hexadecimal-chars>.hcp.westeurope.azmk8s.io:443
  name: <kubernetes-cluster-name>
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: <kubernetes-cluster-name>
    user: clusterUser_<resource-group-name>_<kubernetes-cluster-name>
  name: <kubernetes-cluster-name>
current-context: <kubernetes-cluster-name>
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: clusterUser_<resource-group-name>_<kubernetes-cluster-name>
  user:
    client-certificate-data: <some long base64 string here>
    client-key-data: <some long base64 string here>
    token: <some secret string of hexadecimal chars here>
```

In GitLab form, I have to input these fields:

1. Kubernetes cluster name
2. API URL
3. CA Certificate - Certificate Authority bundle (PEM format)
4. Token
5. Project namespace (optional, unique)

I tried these values:

1. I put my `<kubernetes-cluster-name>` to match the name of the cluster on azure and the cluster name on the `.kube/config` file.
2. I put the url `https://<resource-group-name+some-hexadecimal-chars>.hcp.westeurope.azmk8s.io:443` copied from the `.kube/config` file.
3. I tried first the `certificate-authority-data` from the `.kube/config` file, but didn't work and I already tried all three base64 strings from the `.kube/config` file, none worked.
4. I put the token from the `.kube/config` file.
5. Leave this empty, as it is optional.

In GitLab, When I try to hit the button `Install` to install the Helm Tiller, I got this error:

```
Something went wrong while installing Helm Tiller
Can't start installation process. nested asn1 error
```

And sometimes I get this error instead:

```
Kubernetes error: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed
```

I'm trying to make this to work since yesterday, had google it a lot and doesn't find anything.

I think the problem is with this 3rd field, the CA Certificate, maybe there are some other way to get this content from the command line `az` or `kubectl`.

Are there someone here that already got this Kubernetes integration from GitLab to Azure AKS working?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found out later that the base64 string in the `certificate-authority-data` of the `.kube/config` file that I was coping its content into the `CA Certificate` field of GitLab "Add Kubernetes cluster" form, it is the PEM format, but base64 encoded.

The PEM format already is a base64 encoded representation of the certificate bits, but it has some line breaks in the middle. This whole content is base64 encoded again before it goes to the `.kube/config` so it is turned into a big base64 single-line string.

I just had to base64 decode this big single-line string (I used the javascript `atob("....")` in the Chrome's Console window), what gave me something like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEyDCCArCgAwIBAgIRAOL3N8oMIwWIxcFTZhTkfgMwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAw
...
...
...
5gP7yoL1peZ+AWjCgcUVZYiItqrBLpWYDgY9g8btYDUIiWlqkmC0+kBaPfwCtckx
cUp3vlwRITrv0mzrxiQjTLTUpEy7EcD+U6IecA==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Then I just copied this content into the GitLab "CA Certificate" field and it worked.

Comment: Thank you! Your hint really helped me out! I wasn't aware, of the base64 encoding.

Comment: hey, just want to add that, you can run the following command to do this for you: `kubectl config view --raw -o jsonpath="{.clusters[?(@.name == 'YOUR_CLUSTER_NAME')].cluster.certificate-authority-data}" | base64 -d | openssl x509 -text`

Answer (score 0):

Decode "certificate-authority-data" value using any decoder
https://www.base64decode.org/